# Alternate JAR for Avalon framework JAR

Tags: java, jar

I'm new to one to the application and I found a usage of Apache Avalon framework jar which have been closed. So I'm trying to find any alternate JAR equivalent to Avalon framework jar.

For references: http://avalon.apache.org/closed.html

So can anyone suggest me what is he usage of this jar and any alternate jar for this as this jar is closed.

Thanks In advance... :)

Comment: The linked page already mentions: It has been split into several smaller projects. Check their documentation and use those you need. You still have to invest some work into this yourself.

Comment: @JanHenke So avalon-framework 4.2 jar is still available in market and it is not retired. this is what you are saying.? Apache avalon jar have been split into different jar files.

Comment: No, when you read the page it is stated clearly. The framework as a whole does not exist any more. But all the functionality has been split into several new projects. So take a look at those new projects (they are linked from the page you mentioned in your question). Pick those which provide the functionality you need.